# function setTimeout in loop

Tags: javascript

If I use setTimeout in a loop so only after the loop ends it executes all the operation in the same time.
I tried to put setTimeout in a separate function, as suggested by many articles, but it does not help.
The code is very simple:

```
function foo(i)
{
    setTimeout( function() {console.log(i);}, 2000);
}

for (let i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    foo(i);
}
```

It prints
0
1
2
3
4
in one shot

Comment: because your 4 setTimeOut are started at the same time

Comment: Sure because JavaScript is **asynchronous**. which means you call the `foo` function immediately 5 times. Or let's say, talk to JavaScript: *Give me print out 0 in 2 secs, and 1 in 2 secs...* So after 2 secs, you get the result one by one.

Comment: Suggested to read the [**JavaScript Info Tutorial**](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#nested-settimeout) has part *Nested SetTimeout*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the proccess registry the 5 setTimeout at almost the same time.

Try with the different timeout time like this:

```
function foo(i)
{
    setTimeout( function() {console.log(i);}, 1000 * i);
}

for (let i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    foo(i);
}
```

Comment: Working! 
Whats the reason that it doesnt print after 1 seconds and 2 seconds and 3 seconds etc...? Do you have a good source to read?

Comment: @OzHarary OP if you found this answer is useful, please accept it by clicking the check mark which's at the left side of an answer.  Which means it solved your problem.

Comment: @OzHarary in the original post you're queueing 5 executions of the setTimeout with a 1 second delay immediately, whereas this takes the loop count into account.

Comment: `setTimeout( console.log, 1000 * i, i);`

Answer (score 1):

you could also do it with a generator. a generator can pause midway through a function
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-generators/

```js
function* generator() {
    let index = 1;
    while (index <= 5) {
        yield index++;
    }
}

let f = generator();


var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
  const obj = f.next();
   if (obj.done){
   clearInterval(interval);
   } else {
    console.log(obj.value)
   }
}, 1000);
```